# ContainerURL not works in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I'm following a tutorial to upload files to Azure Storage Blob using Spring Boot. At some point in the code, when I try to use the `ContainerURL` it turns red and I can't import it into the project. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Have you added the relevant maven/gradle dependency to the project?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please, instead of including your code as image, include it with the **code sample** tool from the text editor and provide enough code to reproduce a minimal example of your problem, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well.

Comment: yes, i entered.